# Objective C: Drag and Drop on a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am making a book application and i used UIScrollView for paging. Everything is going pretty well but when i started coding the function for drag and drop Images it's not working, but the code works in my other projects without the UIScrollView.

Is it possible to apply drag and drop functionality on a UIScrollView?

here's my code

```
    image1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];
    [image1 setFrame:CGRectMake(2834, 225, 150, 184)];
    [scrollPaging addSubview:image1];

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    image1.center = location;
}
```

Comment: The touch event is probably being received by the scrollview. Did you check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to disable scrolling on the scrollview when you detect that you are starting to drag an item (I use a delayed selector to determine a start drag operation), and re-enable scrolling once you release the touch.

To disable scrolling use...

```
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:FALSE];
```

Comment: i have the same question as his and i also used setScrollEnabled but i think i did it wrong.i also posted a question, here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723178/objective-c-stop-scrolling-on-touch/8723232#8723232

Answer (score 0):

Try delaying the touches using canCancelContentTouches property or try subclassing each of the individual images as a separate view and implement touches for all of them together in this class.

Comment: This won't work when subclassing a UIView and using touchesMoved etc, the scrollview interprets that as a normal scroll event. The trick is to disable the scrolling on the scrollview when you detect that you are dragging an item.

Answer (score -1):

I use a UILongPressGestureRecognizer and it's UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded in the view controller that the scroll view is inside of.

Comment: He isn't using gesture recognisers, answer the original question and don't downvote competing answers when they are more valid than your own.

Comment: He hasn't said he ONLY wants to use touchesMoved. He would do far better to use gesture recognizers. Your answer if not a good one imho.

Comment: Feel free to suggest alternatives, but please refrain from blanket-downvoting other answers to try to secure reputation, it is not good practice.

Comment: I don't blanker-downvote - in fact I rarely down vote. But your answer is plain wrong.

Comment: I am not going to discuss this any further with you, suffice to say, whilst your approach may solve the problem by introducing a new approach, my solution DOES work and works with the current approach taken by the OP. Apologies if this does not sit well with you, but it is the truth.