# Objective C: Stop Scrolling on Touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am trying to temporarily stop the scrolling of my view when the user starts to touch the screen and move.

I have coded this

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (touch){
        [scrollView setScrollEnabled:FALSE];
    }
}
```

it is not working.

Comment: Where are you overriding touchesBegan? in the scrollview? or the draggable view?

Comment: I think that is your issue, in my version I track touches in the view I want to drag, it then tells the scrollview to stop scrolling but the view I am dragging continues to receive touchesMoved events.

Comment: ah, so i need a separate view for the touch event?

Comment: Well in my case I tracked the touches in the view I actually wanted to drag, however if you move that view, the touch location will never change as you are moving the view with the touches. I have a copy which I move to solve this. I can send code if you like.

Comment: really? can you?? it'll be great help! here's my email add ohnochano@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ScrollView and the User touches it its Defaults beheviour that it stops to scroll.

If this is not whatyou ment please be more specific what you want ;)

Comment: i want to temporarily disabled the Scroll so that i can do dragging images.

Comment: If you want to drag images Try the Longpress Observer. (So that you simulate the same behaviour as you drag Apps) And if the Image is draged you can enable scrolling again. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    - (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
           [scrollView setScrollEnabled:FALSE];
    }
```

now i just wonder where you enable it again...